# AMPscript variable in push activity body message

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, mobilepush, push-notification

I'm trying to use SSJS to parse the JSON coming from IS in a push activity in JB to populate an AMPscript variable in the body of the message. The testers are receiving a blank message while the preview shows expected values. In addition, if I put the variable in the Title or Subtitle it shows the expected output - in preview and for testers. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Script code:

```
%%[
  SET @subscriberKey = AttributeValue('ContactKey')
  /* IS Triggered Products Parse */
  SET @triggerRecommendationJson = AttributeValue('Trigger_Catalog_Items')
  
]%%
<script runat="server">
   Platform.Load("core", "1");
  
   var triggerCatalogItems = Platform.Variable.GetValue('@triggerRecommendationJson'); 
   var payloadObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(triggerCatalogItems);
   var numProductsTrigger = payloadObj.length;
  
    if (numProductsTrigger > 0) {  
        var catalogItem = payloadObj[0]
        var productName = catalogItem.name
        
        Platform.Variable.SetValue('@productName', productName);
    }
  </script>
```

Push notification message:

```
%%=ContentBlockById(88421)=%%
%%=v(@productName)=%%
```

The payload:

```
[
    {
        "price":79,
        "imageUrl":"image url",
        "name":"product name",
        "url":"url"
    }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide us with the actual script in your referenced content block, as it otherwise is nothing more than a black box

Comment: @LukasLunow updated

Comment: What kind of push activity are you using in the JB? You should put some data in the DE so we can visualize it as well

Comment: @DucLe there is only one push activity in journey builder. I've added the payload